# How to launch my pwa to my Android mobile phone

Tags: android, angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWAs and create a simple PWA with angular-cli.

I can run successfully my app to the browser. But I would like to launch it on my mobile device as an app. I cannot locally access my app on my mobile through browser because my PC and mobile are in diff networks. How can I launch it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to test your PWA on your mobile device while developing? You could build and then deploy to a free HTTPS host like https://Glitch.com to test that it installs as expected without errors on your Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly install it on your mobile device such as mobile application.

But you need to add an install button on your web page -> open it from mobile -> click on it

the browser will check if all the requirements are met to install on device and therefore proceeds

> Starting in Chrome 68, Chrome will fire the beforeinstallprompt event
>   every time the user visits your app (but won’t necessarily suggest to
>   install). You can catch this event to create a custom install button.
>
> First you need to know that the event fires only once, and pretty
>   quickly! You’ll want to listen to it as soon as you can. Let’s add
>   this in the constructor our PwaService we created earlier:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', event => {  
> this.promptEvent = event; });
```

> If the event fires, we keep it in the
>   service. We can then check if installation is possible like so:

```
 <button *ngIf="Pwa.promptEvent" (click)="installPwa()">   Install
 </button> And in the component:

 constructor(public Pwa: PwaService) {} installPwa(): void {  
 this.Pwa.promptEvent.prompt(); }
```

> Clicking on the button will show the
>   user the browser’s dialog for adding the app to the home screen.

You can check [this](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/turn-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-4-easy-steps-543510a9b626) link for more details

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info. But as I said I cannot access my app through the browser of my device because my pc and my mobile are connected to diff networks. Can 't I somehow launch it as an app and then install it via an app store or any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think that this is possible because after all it's a website, however there are some tools that generates an APK for a PWA online, but we all now what they do, the put it in a webview and output the APK  and i don't think that's what you're looking for

Comment: Okay. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your facing difficulty regarding the network , you can create a hotstop/adhoc from your PC and connect your mobile to it, so they can be in the same network